# FFmpeg AAC audio copy

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac

I tried to convert some transport stream files to MP4 files, keeping only the original audio.
For most streams this works fine, but for streams containing aac audio this seems an issue.

- q1: why this error as I am only copying the audio, not encoding.
- q2: is there a way to overcome this, re-encoding is not an option.

instruction:

```
ffmpeg -i Test_aac_DVB_h264_25fps.trp -acodec copy -vn Test_aac_Audio.mp4
```

Error message:

```
[mp4 @ 000001605f169280] Could not find tag for codec aac_latm in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 2):

The MP4 muxer does not allow aac_latm. Either:

- Re-encode the audio with `-c:a aac`
- Or use a different container format such as `.ts`, `.m2t`, or `.mka`.

See [#3244 Support LATM AAC in MP4 container](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3244).